# Issue in Content Query and Summary Link Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have migrated Page from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2013 (Online). While I am trying to add Summary link webpart or Content Query webpart in the page it is giving the following error.

> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open
>   this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML
>   editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists,
>   contact your Web server administrator.

Can you please share any solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I remember that error and I if I remember well, the only solution was to recreate the page from scratch.
In my case it took less time that troubleshouting the issue.

Comment: I finally got some solutions. There were some issues in the items style file that were creating the problem while migrating from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint Online 2013